# Como organizar o eixo x com seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico sazonal com o seaborn (linhas representando os anos e meses no eixo X), ele está saindo até corretamente, exceto por uma questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o eixo X se trata de strings ele as coloca automaticamente em ordem alfabética. Há alguma forma de reorganiza-los pela ordem dos meses?

Segue o meu código:

```
sns.lineplot(data = diario, x = 'MÊS', y= '2010',marker = 'o') 
sns.lineplot(data = diario, x = 'MÊS', y= '2011',marker = 'o')
sns.lineplot(data = diario, x = 'MÊS', y= '2012',marker = 'o')
sns.lineplot(data = diario, x = 'MÊS', y= '2013',marker = 'o')
sns.lineplot(data = diario, x = 'MÊS', y= '2014',marker = 'o')
sns.lineplot(data = diario, x = 'MÊS', y= '2015',marker = 'o')
sns.lineplot(data = diario, x = 'MÊS', y= '2016',marker = 'o')
```

E esse é o formato atual dos dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort=False` para impedir que o seaborn tente reordenar os valores nos eixos X e Y antes de plotar.

Aqui um exemplo com dados aleatórios:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

meses = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr']
anos = ['2010', '2011', '2012']

# Dados aleatórios
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(len(meses), len(anos))), 
    index=pd.Index(meses, name='Mês'),
    columns=anos,
    ).reset_index()
print(df)
# output:
#    Mês      2010      2011      2012
# 0  Jan  0.714205  0.271607  0.934972
# 1  Fev  0.131348  0.817726  0.255650
# 2  Mar  0.582372  0.028167  0.445797
# 3  Abr  0.967894  0.913658  0.387183


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for ano in anos:
    sns.lineplot(ax=ax, data=df, x='Mês', y=ano, marker='o', sort=False)
ax.set_ylabel('Ocorrências')

plt.show()
```

Figura resultante:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]